# C# : Classes into Folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory

I want to organize my solution by adding folders and organize classes into them
how to access these classes as i tried to access them but can't
folders looks like packages in java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you create a folder in the Visual C# project it normally creates a [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for items created in that folder. You need to add a `using blah.foldername` statement to the c# file where you are trying to use the items from the folder, or you can edit the file in the folder to use `namespace blah` instead of `namespace blah.folder`.

Comment: what if there was no namespace?

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio mimics your project's hierarchy on the hard drive.  When you add a solution folder within Visual Studio, it creates a *real* folder under your project directory.  Any new projects or source files you add to the solution folder in Visual Studio will default to that directory.  Also, *and this gets to the heart of your question*, when you add a C# file, i.e., class, to the solution folder, Visual Studio places it in a *sub*-namespace of your project.

For example, if your project is named *MyProject*, the default namespace will be **MyProject**.  If you add a solution folder to *MyProject* called *MyFolder*, any new files, i.e., classes added to that folder from within Visual Studio will have a default namespace of **MyProject.MyFolder**.  Thus, in order for classes in the **MyProject** namespace to reference classes in the **MyProject.MyFolder** namespace, you need to either fully qualify the class name, e.g., **MyProject.MyFolder.MyClass** or include a `using MyProject.MyFolder;` statement at the top of file where the class is used.

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking about solution folders, they don't translate to the resulting code. They are merely a way to organize your projects.

If you are creating folders in your project to separate code files, then traditionally we would have the namespace represent the hierarchical structure of the solution/project.

Then you just include the namespaces as you normally would.

Does this answer your question?